# Attached file in gmail has the name "noname

Tags: android, gmail

When I am sending a mail though android with an audio attachment, the downloaded file has the name "noname" and it is not played by any media player.

When the extension of the file is changed to .3gp, then the file works with gom player, vlc etc. Why is this so? And what is the remedy?

Comment: can you place your code where you are sending the email...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the same issue as this:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/L0rwZfE1exc

Best answer in that thread from Retailmessiah:

> "It happens with certain encodings from different MacOS computer, but
>   MORE COMMONLY it happens when a person sends a forward using Microsoft
>   Outlook. Outlook encodes the previous thread in some kind of modified
>   rfc-822 encoding that GMail doesn't play nice with."

Might want to look closer at the encoding on the file attachment?